# Is protovis still being actively developed?

Tags: charts, javascript, protovis

Based on the commit history, it looks like protovis has not been touched since August 2010. Has the project been abandoned?

http://gitorious.org/protovis/protovis/commits/master

I'm evaluating javascript charting libraries for my company and would hesitate to recommend one that is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protovis is no longer being actively developed; instead, it has been reincarnated as D3.js:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/

There is an [introduction for Protovis users](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/protovis.html) that elaborates on the major differences, and why we decided to develop a new library rather than make incremental improvements.

Comment: Thanks. There's a typo in that link above. http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/protovis.html